# Angular Material CSS not applied on first load

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display an avatar in the header of an Angular app as follows (in a component located in a sub-folder `core/header/header.component.html`):

```
<span *ngIf="user?.photoURL">
    <img mat-card-avatar src="{{user.photoURL}}" alt="Avatar">
</span>
```

> `AppMaterialModule` is imported in `app.module.ts`

At first load the avatar style is not applied (picture is fully displayed) but once I starting navigating within the app, the style is applied to the picture (whichever page I go).

Any idea?

Comment: How is your material theme imported?

Comment: @Robertgarcia in `style.scss` (first line): `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';`

Comment: Try instead to add it in your angular.json in the styles array styles: ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",]

Comment: @Robertgarcia it looks like I was already doing that. Any other idea?

Comment: Try to reproduce it in an stackblitz, are you using SCSS or maybe importing your styles lazy?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with avatar!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue; the component you are using this in needs to have a mat-card element or needs to be wrapped in it. Adding an empty mat-card works the same as adding one on the side with display: none!

```
<mat-card> your avatar html </mat-card>
```

or

`<mat-card></mat-card>` in the same component html somewhere else.